# placing an interval in an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I tried emailing my Professor for help with this and he was not very helpful.

given an interval of size 50 starting at x as [x,x+50] (x and x+50 are included), find where to place this interval so that it has the maximum number of elements pointed by the array in it. Consider only intervals that start at a number in the set. I'm really stuck on this one.

He gave us the array of random pointers, so that's his code. I've sorted it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, n, temp, j, k, x;
    int *info[100];

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        info[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *info[i] = rand() % 1000;
    }
    for (k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
        for (j = k; j < 100; j++) {
            if (*info[k] > *info[j]) {
                temp = *info[j];
                *info[j] = *info[k];
                *info[k] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
        if (*info[k/50] = 1)
            printf("%d\n %d\n", *info[k], *info[k] + 50);
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maximum number of elements?  [x,x+50] will always have exactly 51 elements, no matter what x is.

Comment: Consider the following simple example with array elements
6 11 9 2 4 7 14
With an interval of size 3 [x,x+3], placing the interval at x=6, [x=6,x+3=9] has the most number of elements in it since 3 elements (6,7 and 9) are in it. This question makes no sense to me.
his example

Answer (score 1):

This is an honest homework question.
StackOverflow recommends to help but not solve
(and later post the solution code, which I just tested).

So here are some hints:

- Summary: I feel that the lesson here is supposed to teach distinguishing between arrays and ranges of values, and between indexes and value of members at those indexes.
- there multiple "ranges/arrays" involved
- the array of 100 random values
- the random values are in the range `[0,1000)`
- the relocateable range of `[x,x+50]` is almost always a sub-range of the value range
  (it might go beyond 1000)
- values of members of the random array can be within the range, 
  that is a boolean attribute
- whether an index into the random array is inside the range is irrelevant
- each possible position of the range starts at a value of a member of the random array
- so you have 100 possible positions of the range to check
- for each of them, count the number of values 
  (of members of the random array which are inside the range)
- (sorry if this sounds like "haha", but) I think sorting only distracted you from the solution;
  at least if, at the beginning, you skip optimisation schemes

With

```
"VRA":=range of possibe values in random array  
"."  :=position of the value of one member of random array  
       (only a few examples, instead of 100) 
"r"  :=possible range,  
       starting at the value of one member in random array,  
       ending 50 later


VRA [  .    ..        . .  . ...             .   .  ..              . )
    0                                                                1k
2 r    [    ]
2 r         [    ]
1 r          [    ]
3 r                   [    ]
3 r                     [    ]
4 r                        [    ]
3 r                          [    ]
2 r                           [    ]
1 r                            [    ]
2 r                                          [    ]
3 r                                              [    ]
2 r                                                 [    ]
1 r                                                  [    ]  
1 r                                                                 [    ]
```

Note that the dots do not change position if you sort the random array.

In my case (which, on my machine, is repeatable, because the randomizer is not seeded) the answer is 10 hits, in a range starting at 703, which is index 62 of sorted random array. And with unsorted array the result is the same, just at 40.
*Offtopic: This disappointed me. If we have a "forty-something" and a "something-two", then it should have been 42 of course. Well, cannot be helped, the effect of narrativium is not so stronge in this universe. (Yes, I know I am mixing quotes from two authors.)*

Comment: So I shouldn't have sorted? Right now my code gives back 1 and 51. I guess each time I should get back different numbers. We haven't learned about trees or anything if that's what you meant about optimization schemes.

Comment: Not exactly "shouldn't", more of "needn't, and it pushes you onto the wrong track". If your intention was not optimisation anyway, then either ignore my comment, or do not sort - but just for making things easier.

Comment: Do not be surprised if you always get the same result. To change that, you would have to seed the random number generator.